# radio button in android - crashes if none selected

Tags: javascript, android

I use the code below in an android app to check for the selected radio button in radio group, it work well but crashes if none of the radio buttons is selected.

How do I wrap this in an if statement to prevent the app from crashing?

```
    checkRadioButtonId =    genderRD.getCheckedRadioButtonId();// get selected radio button from radioGroup
    checkedRBValue =        (RadioButton) findViewById(checkRadioButtonId);       // find the radio button by returned id
    radioButtonText =       checkedRBValue.getText().toString();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need to wrap it in an `if` statement, otherwise when you reach the `checkedRBValue.getText()` line it will crash because `checkedRBValue` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm unable to compile it right now but you could try:

```
if(checkRBValue != null){

//enter your code here.

}
```

Hope this helps. :)